# How to get image out of partial Base64 string

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing

The third party API I am using returns (amongst other things) a base64 encoded image, however it is, according to the spec, a `Base64, header stripped representation of the image.`.

Sample string looks like this:

> AD8AoyoBkKchTQpwQM8U9ogoBO8Z9xSEpx978xRcC3hXgiBJBX9aqsZLaYHgnqKtwkFBwGGO5qC6CtIM5Bx0FTfUdisSXYscZPYUbyOKlaEJ1DjNJ5K+rVQiNxh2X0OKlWJNueSaknhaSYNEpbd1AFRDKsVYYPpQgJ0GyJMAHLYxjNRNGGY7uuetWCxFtEB/fJqOcfvJTuVeTjPf6UWArAEE4PQ8U/zh3HNMXOCBTCDnoaALhlcjliB6Co3kVmy3LDuTVbJrX01ENqGKqTk84oYFeKQdDx6UTbSm484Pekl++3+9UtuoaRgwBGD1FR1K6FXCY3Dbn0yc0nmL/k1G/Ehx61HVE3P/2Q==

How can I convert it to an image on the client side?
I tried adding various prefixes in the front of the string, like `image/jpeg;base64,` but it didn't work.

Comment: seems that your data is bad. you can use this decoder to compare the output with the input: 
 (https://www.opinionatedgeek.com/codecs/base64decoder)

Comment: Yes, the data looks incomplete, that's why I wonder if I should try to add a "image header" somehow?

Comment: is there a reason why you are stripping those at the first place? adding data to the encoded string does not sound like a sound approach.

Comment: I am not stripping this data, it comes like this from the third party API.

Comment: and arty you sure that its jpeg?

Comment: No, I don't know the type. I tried adding different types (gif, png, jpeg). Jpeg is most likely, though.

Comment: 3rd party APIs should have a documentation, no?

Comment: I wouldn't ask here if it had.